# name for a matrix operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, terminology

If $A$ is a matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix, is there some special name for $DAD$?

Comment: The paternal matrix? ;)

Comment: Interesting idea :)

Comment: $A$ diagonally conjugated by $D$?

Comment: Or just $A$ conjugated by $D$.

Comment: I'd reserve the word "conjugated" for something like $DAD^{-1}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it is called "diagonal congruence" [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/03081080600872327). This makes sense, at least when $D$ is real, since it is a [congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence). "Conjugate" sounds more like $D^{-1}AD$ or $\overline{A}$ to me.